# How do I avoid busy loop in Java Thread with callback function

Tags: java, multithreading, callback

I am trying to figure out how to eliminate a busy loop in a thread I have in Java.  The thread does nothing but wait for a callback from the Listener class.  The thread class looks something like this:

```
class MyThread implements Runnable, MessageListener{
  private Listen Listener;

  public MyThread(){
    Listener = new Listener(this);
  }

  public void run(){
    while(true){}
  }

  public void messageReceived(Message m){
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

I have tried to make this code as simple as possible.  The idea is that Listener is waiting to receive some data from a serial port and when a message is received the thread will do some processing on it. I would prefer to use some synchronized variables such as a BlockingQueue of Message but I can't modify the Listener code.  The issue, of course, is that the run loop eats up processor cycles.  My questions:

If I wait or sleep in the run loop will the function call still work as expected? (I'm not sure how to test that this works 100% of the time).

Is there some better way to avoid this loop altogether?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what this actually does without seeing what is actually inside the `while(true){}` loop and the `messageReceived` method.

Comment: Something does not seem right here. Does the Listener create it's own thread? Because if it does, and it doesn't explicitly post-back (wait, *how is it doing that*?) to this one, but just calls a method ... and if it doesn't create it's own thread ...

Comment: @pst Indeed the listener does create its own thread.  On some digging through the libraries related to it I found that it creates a thread and that there is a constructor so that I can create this thread from within my own.  I can then do a join rather than the busy loop.

Comment: Why does the thread exist when there is nothing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this

```
class MyThread implements Runnable, MessageListener{
          private Listen Listener;
          private Object lock = new Object();
      public MyThread(){
        Listener = new Listener(this);
      }

      public void run(){
        while(true){
            synchronized (lock) {
                try{
                    lock.wait();
                    // use the updated status
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
      }

      public void messageReceived(Message m){
          synchronized (lock) {
                try{
                    // Do something with the message here like update some status
                    lock.notify();                      
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

      }
    }
```

Once you get the event, you update some status/ store the message and release the notifying Thread. Then from your thread process the event

Comment: This helps a lot for what I'm trying to do.  Between this and finding the the thread that Listener runs (not mentioned in the documentation)  so that I can do a join before allowing this thread to finish its work and exit my problem is completely solved.  I don't know why I didn't consider this previously.  Thank you.

Comment: It messageReceived gets called before the call to lock.wait(), then the wait will not end and the message will not be handled.  There should be a while loop for messageNotAvailable around the call to lock.wait().

Answer (score 2):

Going just by what you're posted, it looks like someone has misunderstood what a thread is and how it works.  If there really is nothing inside the while(true){} and it's not that you just clipped it out for brevity, then handling the message doesn't actually happen on this thread.

Code does *not* run "on a thread" just because the method is defined on the implementation of runnable.

When your `messageReceived(Message m)` method is called, the body of that method executes in the calling thread.  It does not get 'handed off' to this thread simply by virtue of being defined there.

Comment: I really like that sentence, trying to make it stand out :)

Comment: Much code was in fact removed so that my example would be easier to see.  The issue I was having was that eventually I want this thread to end but only once Listener is done (it turns out Listener has an internal thread that I am able to do a join on.

There was one misunderstanding I have and that was whether a callback method such as this is executed in the current thread or calling thread.  I had never fully considered this but what you say makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing to do your thread doesn't need to exist.

```
class AsyncMessageListener implements MessageListener{
    private final Listener listener;
    private final ExecutorService services = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public MyThread(){
        listener = new Listener(this);
    }

    public void messageReceived(final Message m){
        services.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // process message m
            }
        });
    }
}
```